# How to customize react-bootstrap modal

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Suppose I have a modal like as follows and I would like it such that, when the modal is showing at that time I also want to work on the background. 
In the following code, there is a textbox. I want to work with the textbox(or an audio) when the model is appearing.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './GenericModal.scss';

class GenericModal extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);

  this.state = {
    showModal: false
  };

  this.open = this.open.bind(this);
  this.close = this.close.bind(this);
}

open() {
  this.setState({showModal: true});
}

close() {
  this.setState({showModal: false});
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <div>I am a Bootstrap Modal</div>
      <Button onClick={this.open}>Show Modal</Button>
      <div>
        <Modal className="modal-container" id="demo-class" ref={node   => this.chart = node}
          show={this.state.showModal} 
          onHide={this.close}
          bsSize="small" backdrop={false}
          >

          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>

          <Modal.Body>
            One of fine body.........
          </Modal.Body>

          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
            <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>         
        </Modal> 
         <Button onClick={this.open}>Show Modal</Button>
         <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>  
   );
  }
}

export default GenericModal;
```

Comment: What kind of work with `textbox`? Playing audio is fine, it'll paly on background. What can you do with `textbox` when `modal` about to appear?

Comment: @Jyothi Babu Araja, actually my requirement is like that, take input in the madal while listening and audio on the background, I can play/pause an audio but in the mean time my shown modal will be displayed.

Comment: Yes, you can do that magic in your `open()` method in `sync` or `async`

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Can I have some more words about this. It would be fine if you provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below example flow addresses your requirement.

More form the comments in code.

i.e `onClick` calls wrapper function which has `open` method for `modal` together with your `customizations`.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './GenericModal.scss';

class GenericModal extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);

  this.state = {
    showModal: false
  };

  this.open = this.open.bind(this);
  this.close = this.close.bind(this);
}

open() {
  let _this =  this;
  this.setState({showModal: true}, function(){
    //state is set, i.e modal is loaded in view
    //here you can do whatever like stopping audio
    //_this.stopAudio();
  });
}

close() {
  this.setState({showModal: false});
}

playSomeAudio(){
  //playAudio();
}

stopAudio(){
  //stop the audio
}

doSomethingBeforeOpen(){
  var _this = this;
  //do whatever you want before opening model. i.e palying audio
  //1. in sync:
  this.playSomeAudio(); //audio starts palying before modal starts triggered
  //2. in async
  setTimeOut(() => {_this.playSomeAudio()}, 1); //async by setTimeout, keep your own time
  //Or any
  this.open(); //opens modal
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <div>I am a Bootstrap Modal</div>
      <Button onClick={this.doSomethingBeforeOpen.bind(this)}>Show Modal</Button>
      <div>
        <Modal className="modal-container" id="demo-class" ref={node   => this.chart = node}
          show={this.state.showModal} 
          onHide={this.close}
          bsSize="small" backdrop={false}
          >

          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>

          <Modal.Body>
            One of fine body.........
          </Modal.Body>

          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
            <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>         
        </Modal> 
         <Button onClick={this.doSomethingBeforeOpen.bind(this)}>Show Modal</Button>
         <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>  
   );
  }
}

export default GenericModal;
```